# Irreducible Representations of $\mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z} $

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I‘m just learning about representation theory so I‘m probably missing something trivial, but I‘d still be very happy if someone could help.

In class we looked at the following corollary:
Every finite group has a finite amount of equivalence classes of irreducible representations. If $\rho_1, \dots,\rho_k$ is a list of non equivalent irreducible representations then: $\sum_{i=1}^k \dim(\rho_i)=|G|$ Edit: this should be: $\sum_{i=1}^k \dim(\rho_i)^2=|G|$, where $\dim(\rho_i)$ is the dimension of the vector space on which $\rho(g)$ acts.

I tried to find all the irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z} = \{[0],[1],[2],[3]\}$

I could think of:

$\rho_0: \mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z}  \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{C}), \rho_0(g)=1$ with $\dim(\rho_0)=1$

$\rho_1: \mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z}  \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{C}), \rho_1(g)=e^{i\frac{2 \pi g}{4}}$ with $\dim(\rho_1)=1$

$\rho_2: \mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z}  \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{R}^2), \rho_2(g)= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^g$ with $\dim(\rho_2)=2$

But the squared sum of the dimensions of these representations is already larger than 4, so what am I missing?

Comment: Or is the problem that $\rho_1$ And $\rho_2$ are equivalent? But then I don’t get why my two equivalent representations have different dimensions.

Comment: You either look at representations over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.  Then either $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$ are of dimension $2$ or $\rho_2$ is of dimension $1$. Anyway you mixed fields, which you can't do.

Comment: Oh, does that mean that the corollary I sated only holds over complex vector spaces? That would clear a lot of things up.

Comment: I'm not sure if "only" but the field definitely has to be fixed, you cannot just jump from one to another.

Comment: Your formula on the sum of dimensions is wrong. It should be the square of each dimension. Map a generator of $C_4$ to a primitive $4$-root of unity, this will give you basically all representation by taking powers of that representation. These are all $1$-dimensional hence irreducible.

Comment: Yes you‘re right, should be squared, thank you. Using your suggestion I get the representations „generated“ by $\rho(1)=k$ for $k \in \{1,i,-1,-i\}$, and then the dimensions work out. But what about real representations, how would I do it there, is my example $\rho_2$ valid?

Comment: The second one is reducible. The real representation maps $G$ to $\langle -1 \rangle$ as subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ is a field of characteristic $0$, the group algebra $FG$ of a finite group $G$ is semi-simple. This means it is a direct sum

$$FG=\bigoplus_i \mathrm{End}_{D_i}(V_i)$$ in which $i$ runs over an index set for the irreducible $FG$-modules $V_i$, and $D_i$ is the endomorphism ring of $V_i$ as an $FG$ module (thus each $D_i$ is a division algebra containing $F$). In case $F=\mathbf{C}$ is the field of complex numbers, the only division algebra is $\mathbf{C}$ itself, and it follows that the dimension of $FG$ is the sum of the squares of the dimensions of the irreducible $FG$-modules, as you write.

However, this is not true in general, as your example of $G=\mathbf{Z}/4 \mathbf{Z}$ with $F=\mathbf{R}$ shows. There are $3$ irreducible $\mathbf{R} G$-modules: two one-dimensional ones ("split" over $\mathbf{R}$) and one two-dimensional irreducible representation, on which the generator of $G$ acts by rotations through an angle of $\pi/2$ and which splits upon extending scalars to $\mathbf{C}$ into a direct sum of two conjugate irreducible representations. The sum of the squares of their dimensions is then

$$1+1+4>4.$$

Incidentally, the equality fails in a different way and for a different reason if the characteristic of $F$ divides the order of the group. In that case, the group algebra is not semi-simple, and there are fewer irreducible representations of smaller dimensions, and so over an algebraically closed field of order dividing the order of the group, the sum of the squares of the dimensions of the irreducible representations will be smaller than the order of the group.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it makes sense, I wonder why they can’t just state this in our lecture notes!

Comment: @HenryT. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯